# the notion of complete atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, manifolds

The following picture comes from *foundations of differential geometry volume I*.[image]

According to the definition of *complete atlas*, would it be more precise to call it *maximal atlas*?

Secondly, the statement

> Every atlas of $M$ compatible with $\Gamma$ is contained in a unique atlas of $M$ compatible with $\Gamma$.

can be proved routinely:

Let $\mathscr A=\{\mbox{all the atlases of }M \mbox{ compatible with }\Gamma\mbox{ that contains }A\}$, I guess it is a *set*.
For each chain $\mathscr A_m$ in $\mathscr A$, let $A_m=\cup \mathscr A_m$, then it is in $\mathscr A$: Suppose $(U_1,\phi_1)\in A_1\in \mathscr A_m, (U_2,\phi_2)\in A_2\in \mathscr A_m$ and $A_1\subset A_2$, then $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}:\phi_1(U_1\cap U_2)\to\phi_2(U_1\cap U_2) $ is an element of $\Gamma$ whenever $U_1\cap U_2$ is nonempty, since $(U_1,\phi_1)$ and $(U_2,\phi_2)$ are both in $A_2$. Hence $A_m$ is an bound of the chain $\mathscr A_m$. By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal element in $\mathscr A$.

Can someone verify for me if the proof is correct?

Comment: Are you asking something?

Comment: Oh, I'm asking if it is more precise to call the complete atlas maximal atlas, and if my proof is right.

Comment: I knew it as "Saturated Atlas" but sure, maximal atlas is better. Your proof is correct but it is unnecessary to appeal to Zorn's lemma. Just take the union of all atlases compatible with $A$ to get the maximal atlas.

Comment: @WillM. But I used the condition of the chain in my proof, how to prove without that?

Comment: @WillM How to prove $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}\in \Gamma$ without using $A_1\subset A_2$?

Comment: I wrote "...take the union of all atlases _compatible_ with $A$..." Does that resolve the issue? Otherwise, your proof is OK.